# Why don't style and layout use the android namespace?

Tags: android, xml

Example, when creating this:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/blah"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<include
    layout="@layout/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Possible reason:
`style` and `layout` get processed at compile time, but I am not 100% sure.

EDIT:

Same thing with `package` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source of `LayoutInflater`, there doesn't seem to be a obvious reason why it's `layout` in a include tag and not `android:layout`. I guess since the include tag is a special case in a layout there's no need for the android prefix.

The include tag is not processed at compile time however, else it wouldn't be in `LayoutInflater` now wouldn't it ;)

As for `style`, I don't know for sure, but I think the reason is that namespaced attributes are defined in `XML` and passed as `AttributeSet` in the `View` constructor. The style however isn't passed in that set, but as a separate parameter. So I think the reasoning is that `style` is a parameter that is always there, while namespace prefixed attributes are dynamic and custom for a `View`.

So no definite answer from me, but maybe it helps ;)